# Gradle: Springboot overriding dependencies (jersey and apache httpclient)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle, jersey

I have a very simple springboot application for testing purposes.

Here my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.mandas:docker-client:2.0.2'
}
```

`org.mandas:docker-client:2.0.2` has a transitive dependency on `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.28`. However gradle then pulls version `2.27` instead of `2.28`.

If I run `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client` I get the following output:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27 (selected by rule)
...
org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27
\--- org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:2.27
     \--- org.mandas:docker-client:2.0.2 (requested org.glassfish.jersey.connectors:jersey-apache-connector:2.28)
          \--- compileClasspath

org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.28 -> 2.27
\--- org.mandas:docker-client:2.0.2
     \--- compileClasspath
```

It seems that `spring-boot-starter-web` somehow has a dependency on `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27`. However, if I print all my dependencies with `./gradlew dependencies` I do not see a dependency on `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27` from `spring-boot-starter-web`.

However, searching a bit around the web, i found another way in tracking down a dependency:

```sh
grep -r "2.27" ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/*
```

Like this i was able to track down where version 2.27 was introduced. It seems to be declared in the following poms:

- spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.0.RELEASE.pom
- spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.pom

**My question now is manifold**:

- First of all, why does `spring-boot-starter-web` depend on `jersey`? I was always under the impression that if we want to explicitly use `jersey` over the `spring` implementation we would include `spring-boot-starter-jersey`.
- Why can't I see that `spring-boot-starter-web` depends on `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27` when running `./gradlew dependencies`. Obviously there must be a dependeny on it somewhere as it downgrades the version.
- Why is version 2.28 downgraded to version 2.27? How can I know which policy is applied by spring boot in order to make a choice for a specific version.
- The application is running perfectly fine, but now as i got a version conflict, how should i best handle this? Is it a viable option to just use v2.28 instead of v2.27. I think this also refers to my first answer on why spring-boot is actually using `jersey`.

I know these are multiple questions, however I think it is better to ask them in one question instead of spreading them over multiple ones, as they are all related to the same context.

BTW: This is not only happening with `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client`. Exactly the same thing applies to `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First of all, why does `spring-boot-starter-web` depend on jersey? I was always under the impression that if we want to explicitly use `jersey` over the `spring` implementation we would include `spring-boot-starter-jersey`.

It doesn't. Rather, it depends on Tomcat. You are correct that you would need the jersey starter for auto-configuring that.

> Why can't I see that `spring-boot-starter-web` depends on `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27` when running `./gradlew dependencies`. Obviously there must be a dependeny on it somewhere as it downgrades the version.

Because it doesn't. More on that below.

> Why is version 2.28 downgraded to version 2.27? How can I know which policy is applied by spring boot in order to make a choice for a specific version.

This is the underlying problem. I will explain it below.

> The application is running perfectly fine, but now as i got a version conflict, how should i best handle this? Is it a viable option to just use v2.28 instead of v2.27. I think this also refers to my first answer on why spring-boot is actually using `jersey`.

It depends. In my experience, your dependencies could break both by upgrading and downgrading a transitive dependency compared to that they have been built and tested against, even if it is just a minor version (I am looking at you, SnakeYAML!) So you really just have to give it a shot. Usually it is safer to upgrade than to downgrade, but sometimes it will still cause problems.

---

Here's the deal with the Jersey downgrade.

The Spring Dependency Management plugin is used to control the versions of your dependencies, both the direct and the transitive ones.

When you apply both the dependency management plugin and the Spring Boot plugin, the latter will apply its default versions, which comes from the Spring Boot BOM. You can check which dependencies are managed and in what versions by running `gradle dependencyManagement`.

The idea with all this is that you get a set of dependencies that are known to work well with each other. If you like a different version of one of the managed dependencies, you will have to configure it using the `dependencyManagement` extension (as documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-bom-import-override-dependency-management)).

This is why your Jersey dependency gets downgraded.

I personally don't use the Spring dependency management plugin as I like the way you work with dependencies in plain Gradle. So I usually just do something like this:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

dependencies {
  implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.0.RELEASE")
}
```

In this case, it will by default use the dependencies from the Spring Boot BOM, but not downgrade them if anyone needs a newer version. But it will upgrade them if needed, and you also don't have to specify a version yourself if you don't want to, in which case it will use the one from the BOM.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very detailed information. I think I got it now. Just one thing: Did I understand correctly that spring the spring boot plugin (in conjunction with the spring-dependency-management plugin) keeps a list (bom) with all possible dependencies Spring Boot (at the specific version) could possibly have?  How do they choose which modules (not versions) are included in the bom?

Comment: Yes, you can see the BOM [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml), but I don't know what criteria they use for selecting the modules. They just say `Each release of Spring Boot provides a curated list of dependencies that it supports` and `The curated list contains all the spring modules that you can use with Spring Boot as well as a refined list of third party libraries`.

Comment: Thanks. What i finally did, and seems to be working was adding this to my build.gradle: `ext['jersey.version'] = '2.28'` and `ext['httpclient.version'] = '4.5.4'`. I'm currently still using the Spring dependency management plugin.