# Gradle picks the older version of dependency when resolving conflict

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, gradlew

I’m facing the following issue:

One of the dependencies in my project use different versions of the `liquibase-core`. The project itself doesn’t define dependency on it(Transient dependency). However when I execute the

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

command it seems that Gradle decides to resolve the conflict by using the older version of the library.

```
+--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.16.1 -> 4.5.0
|    +--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.16.1 -> 4.5.0 (*)
```

This brings in vulnerable `liquiase-core` library in my app at the runtime. Could you point me to the documentation that explains this behavior? I read that by default Gradle should use the latest version of the dependency. However it does not appear to be the case here.

I’m using `Gradle 6.9.2`

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: The version might be managed by a plugin. For example if you're using spring boot 2.6.12 the version 4.5.0 of liquibase-core will be chosen.

Comment: I am using spring-boot 2.6.8, and I excluded the liquibase from it, still I am getting same, liquibase-core:4.5.0

Comment: The exclusion won't make the version mgmt. by the plugin go away. But you might find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937991
You can use "dependencyManagement" section specified by the spring dependency-management plugin (https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-dsl) or ditch that pluging.

Comment: consider alternatively to upgrade the version of spring boot if you want to exclude side effects from the version mismatch in the transitive dependencies.